# Fill color inside linestring geometry ggplot or convert linestring into multipolygon

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I would like to use the sf maps provided in some of the mapping packages such as  rworldmap. I am unable though to neither color inside the geometry nor convert to multipolygon which would allow me to use the fill= argument.

```
backg= sf::st_as_sf(rworldmap::coastsCoarse)
ggplot()+geom_sf(data=backg)
```

I understand that since this is a string, the fill argument doesn't work.

```
ggplot()+geom_sf(data=backg,fill='blue')
```

But also trying to convert to multipolygon fails

```
MP=st_cast(backg,'MULTIPOLYGON')
```

Is there anyway to color inside a line/multistring sf?

Comment: are `backg` and `datab` the same thing?

Comment: what would you like to colour?

Comment: @Edo yes sorry, corrected now. I would like to color inside the continent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, but the linestrings don't necessarily make the nice polygons that want. The problem in your example is that row 96 of the sf object contains less than 4 points, so it can't be converted to a polygon. If you remove it however, you can perform the conversion (on the `geometry` column):

```r
datab = sf::st_as_sf(rworldmap::coastsCoarse)

datab <- datab[-96,]
datab$geometry <- sf::st_cast(datab$geometry, "POLYGON")
```

This now allows you to plot, but here you can see the problem with converting linestrings into closed polygons. If the start and end of the linestrings are at different points, you will get an artificial joining line between the start and end. In this example, this ruins the appearance of Africa, Eurasia and South America:

```r
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = datab, aes(fill = as.factor(seq(nrow(datab))))) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for this, this is unfortunate, so I guess the only way would be to manually modify some points. I guess it would be easier to find a coastline map with polygons.